# how to get all instances with a tag under my amazon account using aws java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I want to get all instance id with a particular tag running under my AWS account using java aws sdk. can someone please guide me how can i get this.thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I did it by using filter and for example get all the instances created by same key-pair value

```
DescribeInstancesRequest request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
List<String> valuesT1 = new ArrayList<String>();
valuesT1.add("my-keypair-name");
Filter filter = new Filter("key-name", valuesT1);

DescribeInstancesResult result = ec2.describeInstances(request.withFilters(filter));

List<Reservation> reservations = result.getReservations();

for (Reservation reservation : reservations) {
    List<Instance> instances = reservation.getInstances();

    for (Instance instance : instances) {

        System.out.println(instance.getInstanceId());


    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that for a tag say Environment you will have to append **tag** prefix.
So it will be **tag:Environment**
Filter filter = new Filter("tag:Environment", valuesT1);

Comment: Good catch @rohanagarwal

Comment: Hi, What if we don't know the value of the tag but we need instances with a particular tag set(not null)?